# downloading images : quality of image affect

Tags: android, image, download

When I download images from web and save them to the SDcard in my app, I use the following method:

```
private void saveImageToSDcard() throws IOException {
        File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), getResources()
                        .getString(R.string.directory));
        if (!sdImageMainDirectory.exists()) {
            sdImageMainDirectory.mkdirs();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            reviewImageLink = url[i];

            urlimage = new URL(reviewImageLink);
            input = urlimage.openStream();

            try {
                output = new FileOutputStream(
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                + "/Downloads/" + "photo" + i + ".jpg");
                try {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[2];
                    int bytesRead = 0;
                    while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) >= 0) {
                        output.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {

                    output.close();

                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {

                input.close();

            }
        }

    }
```

The images are saved to sdcard **but** when I try to take the images from sdcard into my application, sometimes the images look blurred.  This doesn't happen all the time, but when it does, parts of the images are very unclear.  What could cause this?

**IMPORTANT**:  I use the following buffer to read the input stream from url:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[2];
```

I've noticed that if I increase its size, then the image saved to sdcard is totally blurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only write as many bytes as you read, the rest of the buffer is zeros  or garbage. Use a buffer of a few K (say, 2048 or 4096), and change your write call to:

```
output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your while loop as follows:

```
while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) >= 0) {
    output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

Because `read` may not read as many bytes as your buffer size. Also use bigger buffer size(like 100*1024), this should not effect image quality, but it should improve performance.

**EDIT**
Regarding blurry images, do you resize your images in any place? That would cause blurriness.

Comment: no, I don't resize the images. I think this  output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
 solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly new to Android development just a beginner but I've been experimenting with this for awhile and in my code I set the bitmap options and then get the bitmap and this seems to work for me, maybe this will help you. Something like this:

```
BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opt.inScaled = false;
opt.inSampleSize = 1;                   
opt.inDither = true;

//Use inPreferQualityOverSpeed option with 2.3.3+
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 10) 
        opt.inPreferQualityOverSpeed = true;
```

And then I use this to get my bitmap from an array index and tell it to use the options:

```
mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), mImageIds[image_index], opt);
```

Using this code and these bitmap options seems to give me the best image quality for the image I want to then write to external storage.

Answer (score 0):

See the code when you are creating Bitmap and using it with view inside app . here changing its properties like size etc will affect quality .